# SQLite How to select multiple columns and return them in order of appearance

Tags: sql, sqlite, pivot

I have 42 columns of data which are consecutive, from column 3 onwards.
I need to select each column in the order it appears. Each row of results must include the first two columns. This is what I have in one row:

```
rowid, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, ......col_42
```

So the result would look like this:

```
rowid col_2 col_3
rowid col_2 col_4
rowid col_2 col_5
rowid col_2 col_6
rowid col_2 col_7
.......
rowid col_2 col_42
```

Then the next row would be listed after that in the same fashion and so on.

I have tried a few things, but multiple select isn't allowed with bracketed select statements.  Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Please post in your question what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

execute the follwing stmt

```
for(i=3;i<=42;i++)
{
nsstring  *strVal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"col_%d",i];
const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@" sélect rowid,col_2,'%@'  from TableName",strVal] strVal]UTF8String];
}
```

Comment: That sure doesn't look like an SQLite statement, I am unfortunately limited to using sqlite.

Comment: if u want to get the desire result by using sqlite and xcode then u can apply my method